# replacing text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page which has the word 'Corian' on it lots of times.

I have to replace it with Corain @reg; (to get registration mark)

I have tried `jQuery("Corian&REG;").replaceAll("Corian");` but it doesn't work.

What should I try please

Comment: `jQuery("Corian&REG;")` is not a selector. Please share Markup code here..

Comment: yes, I kinda gathered it wasn't a correct selector - which is why I asked...

Comment: replaceAll in jQuery works on elements, not strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will solve your problem.

```
$("span, p, div").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    text = text.replace("Corian", "Corian&REG;");
    $(this).html(text);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gu5ffbf5/2/)**

Comment: thanks - but doesn't work. If I use your code as is i get 'TypeError: $ is not a function'. So I replace $ with jQuery and no errors, but nothing replaced...

Comment: Have you placed this after "Ready" event..?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 //alert ('hi'); 
 "use strict";
 
 jQuery("span, p, div").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
 alert ('hi '+text);
    text = text.replace("Corian", "Corian&REG;");
    jQuery(this).html(text);
});
 
});

Comment: ah - its working now!!!! Thanks. I saw in the fiddle that you had `replace(/Corian/g, "Corian&REG;");` .... what does the 'g' do? Thanks very much!

Comment: @maxelcat I updated with your script in my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gu5ffbf5/3/

Answer (score 0):

First get the html use replace with /text/g and assign the html again to body. Also use `®` instead of `&REG` as after rendering it is `®`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MLnBY/225/)**

```
html = $("body").html().replace(/Corian®/g, 'Corian');
$('body').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all children of the body element and replace with a simple regex:

```
$("body").children().each(function() {           
    $(this).html().replace( /Corian/g, "Corian&REG;");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is a solution that enumerates the text nodes of the document and replaces the text.

The reason I do this is that if you swap the whole HTML out you are going to lose all bound events and data in the document - because you are essentially replacing the entire document - breaking everything.

Complimentary fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x51uzqfw/2/

> **IMPORTANT:** The JavaScript provided **cannot** be in the `<body>`. It must be in an external file because the replace method will replace the word 'Corian' inside the JavaScript too.

**JS**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  alert('event');
});

function unescapeHtml(value) {
  var temp = document.createElement("div");
  temp.innerHTML = value;
  var result = temp.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  temp.removeChild(temp.firstChild);
  return result;
}

function recurseReplace(parentNode) {
  var count = parentNode.childNodes.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var node = parentNode.childNodes[i];
    if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace('Corian', unescapeHtml('Corian &reg;'))
    }
    recurseReplace(node);
  }
}

recurseReplace(document);
```

**HTML**

```
Corian
<div>
  <button type="button">
    I have an event! Corian
  </button>
  <div>Corian</div>
  <div>Corian</div>
  <div>Corian
    <div>Corian</div>
  </div>
</div>
Corian
```

**EDIT**
I made a change because I realised that this did not take into account text nodes in the `<body>` root.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you have to select by selector(in your cases you have tried with Corian® which is not a jquery selector ).

```
$("body").html(($("body").html().replace('Corian', 'Corian&REG;'));
```

Get all html of body and replace it by jquery replace function.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MLnBY/224/)

Comment: The replace is backwards on this.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelCoxon fixed :)